# Virtual Address assigned to an imported function

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, portable-executable

Consider an instruction like CALL DWORD PTR 44244100 that imports and uses a DLL function within an assembly program.We know the address used by the instruction is a Relative Virtual Address (RVA).

1.So why do I reach another VA value in the Thunk value field of the LordPE software when I trace that piece of code by it?

2.Whether DLL's such as User32 or Kernel32 always is loaded at a specific VA or not necessarily?
If not so how does Loader recognize which DLL the address mentioned above belongs to? by searching in Name Table?!
I mean this address is invariant,so if the loaded dll's location is fixed too,then another VA should be assigned to this address first.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first question.. If you mean thunk as for function imports those aren't RVAs, those are flat addresses. Also address used by instruction in case of code addressing is always relative to current instruction pointer value. RVAs are only used by loader pretty much (and functions like LoadLibrary, GetProcAddr and these).. I think. **x86 Processor does not know the concept of RVA** that's for sure. Maybe you knew that, it wasn't very clear to me, if that's the case, sorry for lecturing.
Question two! No! It is not fixed! The loader actually goes through import table of your exe and fills in placeholders. Fixed load addresses are no more a thing since windows xp sp3. Hope this helps. If not, this helped me when I was little potato https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx